# Stellaris Launchpad: Register to store value that can be read after soft-reset

Tags: reset, stellaris

I am working with an LM4F120 Stellaris Launchpad. In my firmware I want to trigger a soft-reset but only once. When the firmware gets out of reset it should read from a register to see wheterh the sot-reset already happened and if so branch to another piece of code.

Do you know of any register where I can store a value and from which I can read back the same value even after the soft-reset?

Comment: Any peripherals you aren't using, perhaps?

Comment: Write to the info flash area. It's a space of non volatile memory in the chips flash meant for that.